# Javascript location.replace(url) always give a cached copy in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

(Sorry I accidentally deleted my original post)

I use the following code to redirect the user to a web page:

> `window.location.replace('my.html' + '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime());`

what I want to achieve is that the user should always get a fresh copy, not cached version, from the server when it's redirected from this page to my.html.

This seems to be working fine in Firefox but not in IE7, unless I manually hit F5. Anyway to fix this? Thanks

update: I tried location.href as suggested below and it still does not work in iE7.

Here's more details about my problem:

In my.html, it includes a javascript file at the begining, and in that js file, i have a global variable x. and in my.html, i call `alert("x value=" + x);`. simple enough. now I do the following:

1. edit the js file and change the value of x. deploy the web
   application.
2. go to the redirect page and get redirected to my.html.
   in FF, the alert shows the new value but in IE7 it still shows the old x
   value.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>---</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `location.href` instead of `window.location`?

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the two answers from nathan and Adriano. I.e.

```
location.href = 'my.html?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Worked well when I tested on IE8 (Don't have IE7 installed)